# How i create peer-connection without localStream?

Tags: webrtc, peer-connection

I just want achieve **one client send mediaSteam** and a**nother received the mediaSteam.**
So Receiver client needn't add localSteam.and i just code pc.addStream(null).But not work.
 How i achieve this by WebRtc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `pc.addStream` with `null`. Instead, just don't call it.

- When the receiver is also the *answerer*, this is all there is to it.
- When the receiver is the *offerer*, you need a little extra work:

You need to specify these [RTCOfferOptions](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#idl-def-RTCOfferOptions) to `createOffer`:

```
{ offerToReceiveVideo: true, offerToReceiveAudio: true }
```

The reason is that by default, the offerer only offers to receive the same kinds of streams it is sending. I know, a dumb default, but it gives the offerer a bit more control. On the upside, there's no harm in always specifying these options, if it matches your desired behavior.