# WebRTC - stream only from one peer

Tags: html, webrtc, getusermedia

I made simple WebRTC application and I think that I understand WebRTC framework. I want to add new feature to my app which allows only for one user share audio/video while the second user does not share video and audio.

How can I do this? What will be difference of standard mechanism?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32039141/918910

Answer (score 2):

For this there's no difference in the standard mechanism. When specifying the constraints to `getUserMedia()` you would specify either `{video: false}` or `{audio: true}`. I think you need at least audio, video or data to create an SDP offer. If not, then simply create an SDP answer without attaching any streams.

After connected you can simply disable the audio/video track of the stream using `getAudioTracks()`/`getVideoTracks()` of [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MediaStream). Each track has the `enabled` property which can be set to true or false.

Comment: The party not sharing their video would not need to create a stream or offer at all. It should be enough for one party to open a media stream and create an offer, the other party simply responds to the offer. If you indeed need *something* to even respond to the offer, just open a data channel.

Comment: I modified my answer to reflect your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do not get `MediaStream` and do not call `peerConnection.addStream()` for the user whom you don't want to share his video/audio.

There is one condition if you do this.
You have to add this constraints to `peerConnection.createOffer`

Firefox:

```
{ offerToReceiveVideo: true, offerToReceiveAudio: true }
```

Chrome:

```
{mandatory: { OfferToReceiveAudio: true, OfferToReceiveVideo: true }}
```

You should give this constraints while creating offer because by default it will offer to receive only what stream you add.

Answer (score 0):

To decide dynamically who will only send media and only receive media you can use SDP attribute a=sendonly, a=recvonly for corresponding media to signal this or negotiate this between two party.